# How can I create an ArrayList by size in random order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I am creating an array by using the function below to add the numbers based on the size of my array. Running this creates the array in this order "5, 4, 3 ,2, 1"

I am trying to create this in random order instead of the order from the loop.  Is there a way for me to do this?

```
function ArrayList() {
  let array = [];
  ArrayList.prototype.insert = function(item) {
    array.push(item);
  };
  ArrayList.prototype.toString = function() {
    return array.join();
  };
}

function createNonSortedRandomArray(size) {
  var array = new ArrayList();
  for (var i = size; i > 0; i--) {
    array.insert(i);
  }
  return array;
}

var array = createNonSortedRandomArray(5);
console.log(array.toString());
```

Comment: Random order means repeated values are allowed?

Comment: No, I'd still want the array list to remain the same size. Instead of this as [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] it would be for example [3, 5, 1, 2, 4].

Comment: Not hard to research how to random sort  or "shuffle" an array

Comment: Here's how you can shuffle it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array